# how does this pointer to abstract class c++ "design" translates to c#

Tags: c#, polymorphism, abstract-class

I often use following design in C++ :

```
class M
{
    public;
        AbsC * _p  ;
        M(AbsC * p)
        {
            _p = p;
        }
        Compute()
        {
            double x = _p->DoSomething();
        }
}
```

where `AbsC` is an abstract class. (`M` is not related to `AbsC`.) I am learning `c#` and as far as I know, polymophism takes place with references (vague assertion and surely false at some point as generics do exist), so I am asking myself : how could I mimic the design above, but in `c#` ?

*Remark.* `AbsC` and derived `C` look like :

```
class AbsC
{
    public:
        virtual double DoSomething() = 0;
}

class C : AbsC
{
    public:
        // can have members involved in calculations from DoSomething, or not
        double DoSomething()
        {
            // return a double
        }
}
```

It's quite a "static" class so to speak.

Comment: is AbsC the base class of C (im curious because of the naming) ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you trying to bring unmanaged C++ into managed C++ and need to know how to interface with it from C#?  Or how is one related to the other?  C# has abstract classes and it has interfaces (pure virtuals from C++ world), but not sure how the question relates to those specifically.

Comment: It is clear : I point a design in c++, and I ask : what would be an analogue design in c# ?

Comment: Sort of.  You're assuming there is one-to-one translation.  But C++ doesn't have explicit interfaces, except that pure virtual classes are the way to do interfaces in C++.  What is `AbsC` is not defined, so it could look like a plain abstract class, or interface-y abstract class.  Hence it can be translated in couple of ways to C#.

Comment: @LB2 I finally wrote "an analogue". It is vague indeed but humanly understandable enough to have a meaning. ;-)

Comment: Yes, with the latest update, I would argue that the best way to translate to C# would be to declare `interface AbsC` (which in C# conventioned would be called `IAbsC`) since C++ `AbsC` is a pure virtual class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straight-forward rewrite of your code into C# might look something like:

```
interface AbsC
{
   double DoSomething();
}

class C : AbsC
{
   public double DoSomething() { return 3.14; }
}

class M
{
   public AbsC _p;
   public M(AbsC p)
   {
      _p = p;
   }
   public void Compute()
   {
      var x = p.DoSomething();
   }
}
```

In C#/.NET you would typically prefix an `interface` with `I`, so `IMyInterface`; the code above retains your original naming.

Also note that your original C++ code could be clearer by using `final` and `override` as appropriate.

Comment: Important to note that this is one variation.  ABsC can also be translated as an interface, for example.

Comment: Would that work as well when for an `abstract DoSomething` ?

Comment: @Ðаn just updated my question to show how `AbsC` looks like

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj yes this also works for abstract functions

Comment: @Ðаn How would this translate would `AbsC` have a public member `BS * _pBS` and a public constructor `AbsC(BS* pBS)` where `BS` is a non abstract class ? We couldn't stick to interface right, but what to do ?